# Difficulty sharing physical ethernet device with Xen 4.4

Tags: ubuntu, xen, ethernet

I have a virtualized PowerEdge T320, with a Ubuntu Server 14.04 running Xen 4.4 as host, that I use at my lab to do scientific computations (I'm the admin of the machine). This server has two physical ethernet devices (Intel I350). I set up a guest VM with Ubuntu Server 14.04 to act as a file server with one ethernet card PCI-passed-through. The guest boots fine, the device seems physically present in lspci, the kernel driver is loaded. Yet I cannot get the link to be brought up, neither by DHCP nor by static IP, as if the router were simply not there (I checked/changed the actual cable).

> Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you check/change the port being used on the switch?  Is there any indication that the port is active?  Are the auto negogate settings correct on BOTH ends?  Is the cable between the place you plug in and the switch ok?

Comment: Yes. I don't how to find out. Yes. Yes. For instance when I swap the cables connecting the cards, on the server end, my host ethernet device still works ok.

Comment: Also, could someone please explain why this question is downvoted ? I could use help improving my question, or simply remove/migrate it if you feel this is not the right site.